# FolderBrowserDialog position on screen. VB.Net

Tags: position, folderbrowserdialog

Is it possible, without an insane amount of work, to customize to location of the FolderBrowserDialog when it appears? I was hoping for the ability to position it at the left upper corner of the main form of my application.

Hoping for something like this:

```
Private Sub but_OpenFolderBrowser_MoveTo_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As   System.EventArgs) Handles but_OpenFolderBrowser_MoveTo.Click
'Set up the folder browser
'Set description
Me.folderBrowser.Description = "Select the directory:"
'Set starting location on  screen
Me.folderBrowser.Location = Me.Location
```

Unfortunately I realized that this property is not available and probably not feasible.
Anyone have a solution?